# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/action_menu_layout.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x109001b

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Not sure what the problem is exactly. I see action_menu_layout.xml in the logcat and I'm not sure where that came from. I don't see it listed in my androidmanifest.xml file.  I suppose I need to remove this xml reference from somewhere but I'm not sure where to start?

Here is my main.java:

```
package com.smith.blackjack;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Main extends Activity {

private ImageView dealerCard0;
private ImageView dealerCard1;
private ImageView dealerCard2;
private ImageView dealerCard3;
private ImageView playerCard0;
private ImageView playerCard1;
private ImageView playerCard2;
private ImageView playerCard3;
private ImageView imgResult;
private Button btnDeal;
private Button btnDraw;
private Button btnHold;
private DeckOfCards deckOfCards;
private int[] dealerValues;
private int dealerSum;
private int dealerCardNumber;
private int[] playerValues;
private int playerSum;
private int playerCardNumber;
private InputStream dealerHiddenCard;
private Card dealerCard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dealerCard0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerCard0);
    dealerCard1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerCard1);
    dealerCard2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerCard2);
    dealerCard3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerCard3);

    playerCard0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerCard0);
    playerCard1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerCard1);
    playerCard2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerCard2);
    playerCard3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerCard3);

    imgResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgResult);

    btnDeal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deal);
    btnDraw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.draw);
    btnHold = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hold);

    btnDeal.setOnClickListener(btnDealListener);
    btnDraw.setOnClickListener(btnDrawListener);
    btnHold.setOnClickListener(btnHoldListener); 


    resetGame();

}

private void resetGame(){

    AssetManager assets = getAssets();
    dealerValues = new int[4];
    playerValues = new int[4];
    dealerSum = 0;
    playerSum = 0;
    dealerCardNumber = 0;
    playerCardNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        dealerValues[i] = 0;
        playerValues[i] = 0;
    }

    try {
        InputStream stream; 
        stream = assets.open("cardback.png");
        Drawable cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,  "cardback");
        dealerCard0.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        dealerCard1.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        dealerCard2.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        dealerCard3.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        playerCard0.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        playerCard1.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        playerCard2.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        playerCard3.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        imgResult.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
        deckOfCards = new DeckOfCards();
        deckOfCards.shuffle();
        assets.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Reset Game", "Error Loading", e);
    }
}

public OnClickListener btnDealListener = new OnClickListener()
{
//      @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {


        try {
            AssetManager assets = getAssets();
            InputStream stream;

            // first player card
            Card newCard;
            newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
            playerValues[playerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
            playerCardNumber++;             
            stream = assets.open(newCard.File);
            Drawable cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, newCard.File);
            playerCard0.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            assets.close();

            // second player card
            newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
            playerValues[playerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
            playerCardNumber++; 
            stream = assets.open(newCard.File);
            cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, newCard.File);
            playerCard1.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            assets.close();

            // first dealer card hidden
            newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
            dealerCard = newCard;
            dealerValues[dealerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
            dealerCardNumber++;
            dealerHiddenCard = assets.open(newCard.File);
            stream = assets.open("cardback.png");
            cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,  "cardback");
            dealerCard0.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            assets.close();

            // second dealer card open
            newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
            dealerValues[dealerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
            dealerCardNumber++;
            stream = assets.open(newCard.File);
            cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,  newCard.File);
            dealerCard1.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            assets.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Deal", "Error Loading", e);
        }

    };
};

public OnClickListener btnDrawListener = new OnClickListener()
{
//      @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            AssetManager assets = getAssets();
            InputStream stream;

            // get next player card
            Card newCard;
            newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
            playerValues[playerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
            playerCardNumber++;             
            stream = assets.open(newCard.File);
            Drawable cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, newCard.File);
            switch (playerCardNumber){
            case 3:
                playerCard2.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            case 4:
                playerCard3.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
            }
            assets.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Draw", "Error Loading", e);
        }
    };
};


public OnClickListener btnHoldListener = new OnClickListener()
{
//      @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Drawable cardImage;
        // evaluate player hand
        playerSum = evaluate(playerValues);
        if (playerSum > 21){
            // player losses
        }
        // flip over the dealer hidden card
        cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(dealerHiddenCard, dealerCard.File);
        Card newCard;
        InputStream stream;
        AssetManager assets = getAssets();
        for (int i=2; i<4; i++){
            dealerSum = evaluate(dealerValues);
            if (dealerSum < 16 ) {
                newCard = deckOfCards.dealCard();
                dealerValues[dealerCardNumber] = newCard.faceValue;
                dealerCardNumber++;
                try {
                    stream = assets.open(newCard.File);
                    cardImage = Drawable.createFromStream(stream,  newCard.File);
                    switch (dealerCardNumber){
                    case 3:
                        dealerCard2.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
                    case 4:
                        dealerCard3.setImageDrawable(cardImage);
                    }
                    assets.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e("Draw", "Error Loading", e);
                } 
                if (dealerSum < playerSum) {
                    // player wins
                }
                if (dealerSum > playerSum){
                    // dealer wins
                }
                if (dealerSum == playerSum){
                    // it is a draw
                }
            }

        }


    };
};

public int evaluate (int[]values)   {
    int sumCards = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        sumCards += values[i];
    }
    if (sumCards > 21) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if (values[i] == 11) {
                values[i] = 1;
                sumCards -= 10;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return sumCards;
}

}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 21:59:08.448:E/AndroidRuntime(3070):android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/action_menu_layout.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x109001b
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2145)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2100)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:70)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.getMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:148)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setMenu(ActionBarView.java:427)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:385)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assetmanager has been closed
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:485)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2127)
10-15 21:59:08.448: E/AndroidRuntime(3070):     ... 18 more
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.smith.blackjack"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the root cause, i.e. the last exception in the chain:
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Assetmanager has been closed`

You probably mess around with resources in the Java code, look around, or maybe something is wrong with the Activity lifecycle, anything "hacky" static?

Comment: Find .close() calls, maybe you closed something related to Assets instead of the InputStream(s).

Comment: I do have an assets.close() call in my resetGame() function.. added my main.java

Comment: Then I guess you know what to do :)

Comment: Ok so that helped. I commented out the assets.close(); and it doesn't crash right away,  But when am I supposed to close it?

Comment: I think never. Why do you want to close it? To free up resources you read from it, close the resources (maybe not even needed) and then set the references to null and the GC will do the rest. I think resource loading should be done at startup, based on the method name you want to reset the game state.

Comment: Oh I just saw you added the code. Why don't you put the images to res/drawable and set up them like this (instead of `setImageDrawable`s): `.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);`, then you don't need to deal with Streams and Assets. And instead of newCard.File just store the appropriate resource ID as int.

Comment: I followed some examples from my textbook that suggested putting the files in the assets folder. I may rewrite it, but your suggestion to not do assets.close() helped at least keep it from crashing right away. Thanks!